# How to put images in Amazon aws s3 bucket from localhost using xampp on windows?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3 default s3 disk and error i am getting is :

> AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get
>   local issuer certificate (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: Can you add some code showing what generates the error?

Comment: $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$file_path = '[path-to-folder]/' . $imgname;           
$s3->put($file_path, file_get_contents($image), 'public');

Comment: I think problem is with SSL Certificate. I tried to create self-signed SSL Certificate on wamp but it didn't work for me and i am still getting Privacy Error.